# Prove a criterion for the relative compactness of a set in the space $C^1[a,b]$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Prove a criterion for the relative compactness of a set in the space $C^1[a,b]:$ in order for the set $\Phi \subset C^1[a,b]$ to be relatively compact, it is necessary and sufficient that $\Phi $ is bounded in $C^1[a,b]$ and the set $\Phi'$ of derivative functions from $\Phi $ is equicontinuous

I used the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem. First we prove that if the set $\Phi$ is relatively compact in $C^1[a, b]$, then it is bounded and the set of its derivatives $\Phi'$ is equicontinuous.

1. Let $\Phi$ be relatively compact in $C^1[a, b]$. Then there is a compact subset $K \subset C^1[a, b]$ such that for any sequence of functions $\{f_n\} \subset \Phi$ there is a subsequence converging in $C^1[a, b]$ to a function from $K$. Since $K$ is compact in $C^1[a, b]$, it is bounded in $C^1[a, b]$.
2. Let $\Phi'$ be the set of derived functions from $\Phi$. Consider arbitrary $f, g \in \Phi$. By the finite increment formula (Lagrange's theorem), there is $\xi$ between $a$ and $b$ such that

$$|f'(\xi) - g'(\xi)| = |f(b) - g(b) - (f(a) - g(a))|$$
It follows that

$$|f'(\xi) - g'(\xi)| \leq |f(b) - g(b)| + |f(a) - g(a)|$$

If $|f - g|_{\infty} = \max \{|f(b) - g(b)|, |f(a) - g(a)|\}$, then $|f' - g'|_{\infty} \leq 2|f - g|_{\infty}$. This means that $\Phi'$ is equicontinuous

*Am I thinking correctly?*

Comment: Sequences are off topic in 1, and should prove (directly) that $\Phi$ is bounded. 2. is completely wrong: you forgot $|b-a|$ in the lhs of your [mean value formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) but the main mistake is to believe you have bounded $|f'(\xi) - g'(\xi)|$ for *every* $\xi\in[a,b]$.

Comment: Consider the operator $T:C^1[a,b] \to C[a,b]\times \mathbb{R}$ given by
$Tf=(f',f(a)).$ Then $T$ is continuous and invertible. Therefore relative compactness of a set $U\subset C^1[a,b]$ is equivalent to the relative compactness of $T(U).$